# underline under bootstrap menu link on hover is not appearing correctly?

Tags: css

I have this bootstrap navbar with menu links :

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav nav-spacing">
   <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
     <a [routerLink]="['/home']" class="nav-link"><p class="home">Home</p></a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item nav-item-spacing" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
     <a [routerLink]="['/about']" class="nav-link"><p class="home">About</p></a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item nav-item-spacing" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
     <a [routerLink]="['/contact-us']" class="nav-link"><p class="home">Contact</p></a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

I have the css like this. I ma mentioning just required necessary css that used in this code to keep my quesion summarize.

```
.home {
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 0.7;
 font-family: Nunito;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-stretch: normal;
 line-height: normal;
 letter-spacing: -0.54px;
}

.nav-item-spacing {
  padding-left: 49px !important;
 }
#navbarResponsive li a:hover {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 2%;
 display: block;
 content: "";
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #a560f3;
}
```

When i am hovering over the links so links are under line is appearing under `menu links` but with some margin bottom even i didn't put any margin bottom. Pleae see below image to get in idea.

Here is how they are appearing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with pseudo elements, try something like this:

```
#navbarResponsive li a:hover::after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 30%;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 0%;
    margin: 0 auto;
   border-bottom: solid 1px #a560f3;
}
```

Comment: but i don't want full underline. I want small underline under menu link. You can say i want 30% width underline  of menu link width

Comment: In this case you can use a pseudo element and position in absolute. I will edit my anser

Comment: i used your css but it's still not working properly. I have updated my question you can see the updated question.

Comment: There is probably a line-height for the a. Try to add this:

#navbarResponsive li a {
    line-height: 30px;
}

Comment: should i add this line-heigth to hover css or normal css?

Comment: try normal, so on the a-tag directly.

Comment: nops. It's not working. Still the same result. And also please see that by your css underline is not appearing under the center of menu link.

Comment: Maybe there is a padding, try this:
#navbarResponsive li a { line-height: 30px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; }
You can of course play around with the values

Comment: i can't place padding-top because from that my nav links will move downward. I don' wan that

Comment: try just padding bottom;-)
#navbarResponsive li a { line-height: 30px; padding-bottom: 5px; }

Answer (score 0):

The moving of the links on the right side would be very little because you are adding the border bottom on hover which takes one px from side also.  Try setting border on both in unhovered and hovered one but change the colour from transparent to  #a560f3

Comment: what do you mean by in both hovered and hovered one? it seems the same. hovered and hovered one?

Comment: Auto complete error sry. When the user is not hovering the element then set the border to transparent colour or as the background and when the element is hovered set to your desired colour